# laravel ajax is not sending data

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.3

the data send by ajax query1 is not present in Request nor it is sending json.
js part

```
$('#Course_name').keyup(function(){
    var query1=$(this).val();
    if(query1 != '')
           {console.log(query1);
            $.ajax({
            url:'/getCourses',
            type:"POST",
            data:{query:query1,_token: $('input[name=_token]').val()},
            success:function(data){
            $("#course_list").show();
            $("#course_list").html(data.output);
            $("#Course_name").css("background","#FFF");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

controller part

```
    $query=$req->get('query1');
    $output= $query;
    return response()->json(array('output'=>$output),200);
```

Comment: So what is output did you experiencing ?

Comment: Object {output: null}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
 $query=$req->get('query1');
```

to

```
 $query=$req->get('query');
```

thats the name of the field you are sending from the frontend